# Syntax PHP cURL HTTP Header to include variable

Tags: php, cookies, curl, syntax

Below is a sample of my code. I need to send a field in the header named "Cookie" and it's value should be what i have in the $cookie variable.

Any chance someone could tell me the correct syntax in the array to include the variable in there?

```
$headers = array(
    "Cookie:" .$cookie  
);


curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
```

For example,

First time i "hit" the server i get back

```
Cookie:JSESSIONID=280FC268DDBA4260AB7F9A5C67304C5C
```

If i then send it back to the server like this

```
$headers = array(
        "Cookie:JSESSIONID=280FC268DDBA4260AB7F9A5C67304C5C",   
);
```

It won't respond with a new cookie.
But it won't seem to work when i pass it as an variable.

Comment: Well, basically it is correct. You're not getting the "Cookie" header at all or problem lies somewhere else?

Comment: I am gettgin the cookie correct, which is basically a "JSESSIONID=......".

What i need now is to send that "JSESSIONID=..." back to the server so that it won't send me a new one.

Comment: Yes, i understand, but did you check if server is actually getting "Cookie" header from your request at all?

Comment: Check my edit on the question. Have confirmed that i don't get another cookie if i send the value as fixed.

Comment: Ok, so to answer your edit - please show me the output for `echo '['.$cookie.']';`

Comment: $cookie ='JSESSIONID=6595E835A795F85B82DE767541E3D48E';

$headers = array(
     "Cookie:" .$cookie  
);
echo '['.$cookie.']';


It returns the value i had it appointed too but server keeps sending a new one. At least i don't get a blank screen now and errors.

Comment: Managed to make it work.

To do tests i had to use the latest JSESSIONID i received from the server. 

Thank you for your time